# Pandas.DataFrame.resample inner level of MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I need to resample a Pandas MultiIndex consisting of two levels. The inner level is a datetime index. which needs to be resampled.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

rng = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', '2019-04-27', freq='B', name='date')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, (len(rng), 2)), index=rng, columns=['sec1', 'sec2'])

df['month'] = df.index.month
df.set_index(['month', rng], inplace=True)
print(df)

# At that point I need to apply pd.resample. I'm wondering how to specify the level that I would like to resample?
df = df.resample('M').last()  # is not working;
# I'm looking for somthing like this: df = df.resample('M', level=1).last()
```

Comment: `df.resample('M', level='date').last()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
 df.groupby('month').resample('M', level=1).last()
```

Output:

```
                  sec1  sec2
month date                  
1     2019-01-31    59    87
2     2019-02-28    70    33
3     2019-03-31    71    38
4     2019-04-30    56    79
```

Details.

First, group the dataframe on 'month' or level=0 of the index.
Next, use resample with the [`level` parameter for MultiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html#pandas-dataframe-resample).
The level parameter can use either str, the index level name such as 'date' in this case, or the level number.
Lastly, chain and aggregration function such as `last`.

Comment: This seems to be working. However, can you please explain this solution? Where is the `level` argument in `resample` coming from, etc.?

Comment: Great, I got it! Thanks!